# How to Handle No Internet Connection in Jetpack compose ? using kotlin Flow and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a user interface like this : [image]

I would like to show the UI when internet status in not connected or Error. and i have no idea to run logic code in **try again button** . i want to refresh the page after button was clicked.

How to reach it using jetpack compose, Retrofit , kotlin Flow

**My Repository**

```
interface LoginRepository{

    suspend fun postLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest):Flow<Resource<Login>>

}
```

**My RepositoryImpl**

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val loginApi: LoginApi,
) : LoginRepository{

    override suspend fun postLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Flow<Resource<Login>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading<Login>())
            val result = loginApi.login(loginRequest)

            if (result.isSuccessful) {
                emit(Resource.Success(result.body()!!.toLoginDomain()))
            } else {
                val type = object : TypeToken<Login>() {}.type
                val error: Login = Gson().fromJson(result.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type)
                error.message = result.message()
                emit(Resource.Error(error.toString()))
            }
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<Login>(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occured"))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<Login>("Couldn't reach server. Check your internet connection."))
        }
    }
}
```

**UseCase**

```
class AuthUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LoginRepository
) {
    suspend fun execute(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Flow<Resource<Login>> {
        return repository.postLogin(loginRequest)
    }

}
```

**MyComposable UI INTERNET ERROR**

```
@Composable
fun NetworkErrorDialog(
    navController: NavController = rememberNavController(),
    navigation: String
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.align(TopStart),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img_epod),
                    contentDescription = "logo",
                    Modifier.size(width = 80.dp, height = 50.dp)
                )
            }
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Center)
                .offset(y = -50.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img_no_internet_dialog),
                contentDescription = "logo",
                alignment = Center,
                modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.NoInternetConnection),
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontFamily = Poppins,
                    fontSize = 28.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            )
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.NoInternetConnectionSub),
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontFamily = Poppins,
                    fontSize = 13.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Thin,
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = { navController.navigate(navigation) }, Modifier.width(147.dp), colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    Blue500
                )
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.TryAgain), style = TextStyle(
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to have a state listening for internet connectivity change and the UI must be shown according to the state value. https://medium.com/scalereal/observing-live-connectivity-status-in-jetpack-compose-way-f849ce8431c7